# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (unknown system variable 'language')

Tags: java, mysql, database, ibatis, sqlmap

Anyone who had troubled with this error?

```
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (unknown system variable 'language')
```

Programming with java, mysql, ibatis. Added some codes and existing codes make this error as well.

Below are the error messages.

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown system variable 'language')

at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.init(JdbcTransaction.java:48)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:89)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryForObject(GeneralStatement.java:104)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:566)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:106)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapClientImpl.java:83)
at kes.db.dao.BaseDao.getObject(BaseDao.java:116)
at ocserver.android.service.dao.TB_OC_USER_BADGE_INFO_DAO.confirmNotification(TB_OC_USER_BADGE_INFO_DAO.java:21)
at ocserver.android.service.action.PushNotificationBadgeModAction.requestTEXT(PushNotificationBadgeModAction.java:66)
at kes.controller.TEXTServletAction.requestTEXT(TEXTServletAction.java:82)
at kes.controller.TEXTServletAction.doPost(TEXTServletAction.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And below are my sql statement.

```
    <select id="select_TB_OC_USER_BADGE_INFO_001" parameterClass="TB_OC_USER_BADGE_INFO_VO" resultClass="TB_OC_USER_BADGE_INFO_VO">
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT
                    BADGE_MC,
                    BADGE_WB
                FROM
                    TB_OC_USER_BADGE_INFO
                WHERE
                    USER_ID = #USER_ID#
                AND
                    COMPANY_CODE = #COMPANY_CODE#
        ]]>
    </select>
```

Belows are TB_OC_USER_BADGE_INFO_VO. Didn't bring getter and setter.

```
public class TB_OC_USER_BADGE_INFO_VO {

    private String USER_ID;
    private String COMPANY_CODE;
    private String TYPE;
    private int BADGE_MC;
    private int BADGE_WB; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was firewall. The firewall had blocked java to access to database on other computer. When permitted the access, my program started working.

Answer (score 1):

I change my java connector library to mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar and it works good.
This problem was in mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe using the buggy MySQL Connector/J? See:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/unknown-system-variable-language-on-database-setup-page-when-using-mysql-765400069.html
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77665